# Grails - Many-to-Many Data persistance (EDITED)

Tags: grails, many-to-many, persistence, grails-orm, grails-2.4

Ok, I am lost... I have a domain class `Student` and `Course`. The class `Course` is set. I do not add any new Courses into the table. A student can have many courses and a course can have many students. Please take a look at what I have and direct me to the right way.

```
class Student {
    String fullName

    static belongsTo = [schools: School]
    static hasMany = [courses:Course]

    static mapping = {
        table "STUDENT"
        courses joinTable: "STUDENT_COURSE", key: "COURSE_ID"  
}

class Course {
    String courseName   

    static hasMany = [students:Student]
    static belongsTo = Student

    static mapping = {
        students joinTable: "STUDENT_COURSE", key: "STUDENT_ID"
}
```

Now, when I enter new student information, the view doesn't blow up, so that's  good... But it saves student info but the joinTable `STUDENT_COURSE` is blank. I know somehow I need to pass the PK ID of studnet and course to the joinTable, but I don't know how and where. (Does it go in the studentController under `def save()`?)
<strike>Also, what should `.gsp` look like? This is what I have and I know I have it wrong. `(id="coursetags" is jQuery autocomplete id)`</strike>

My `_form.gsp` input part.

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: studentInstance, field: 'courses', 'error')} required" >
<label for="course">
    <g:message code="student.courses.label" default="Course" />
    <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
</label>
<g:textField name="course" id="coursetags" required="" value="${course?.course}"/>
```

My result should look like this.

```
STUDENT             COURSE                      STUDENT_COURSE
ID      FULLNAME    ID          COURSENAME      STUDENT_ID   COURSE_ID
1       John Doe    1           English101        1             1
2       Jane Smith  2           Science101        1             2
                                                  2             2
```

I've been trying to analyze these sites...

http://chrisbroadfoot.id.au/2008/07/19/many-to-many-relationship-mapping-with-gorm-grails/

https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/GORM.html#manyToMany

https://grails.org/wiki/Many-to-Many%20Mapping%20without%20Hibernate%20XML

Thank you.

**EDIT 1**

My controller

```
class studentController {
    @Transactional
    def save(Student studentInstance) {
        if (studentInstance == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        if (studentInstance.hasErrors()) {
            respond studentInstance.errors, view:'create'
            return
        }  

    def courseID = Course.findByCourseLike(params.course)

    studnetInstance.save flush:true

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'student.label', default: 'Student'), studnetInstance.id])
            redirect studentInstance
        }
        '*' { respond studentInstance, [status: CREATED] }
    }

    def sID = studentInstance.id    //When I println under these, they print the right id numbers.
    def cID = courseID.id

    student.addToCourses(cID).save()  //This is the part that I don't understand.
                                     //I get error saying No such property: student for class.

    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**
So, I was thinking and doing some research.... Unless I use SQL directly to `STUDENT_COURSE` join table, I need to create a separate domain class for `StudentCourse` and map both `Student` and `Course` classes to `StudentCourse`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, when dealing with a many-to-many association you need to

1. call `parent.addTo*(child)` to add instances to the collection, and then call `parent.save()` to persist them.
2. use `key` instead of `column` in both *joinTable* mappings.

In addition, I recommend using the `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` annotation on controller methods which call `save()` so that you won't need to flush explicitly. In your case, `Student` is the owner of the association (because Course is set to `belongTo` `Student`).

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

class StudentController {

    @Transactional
    def save() {
        def student = /* some Student instance */
        def course = /* some Course instance */

        student.addToCourses(course)
        student.save()
    }
}
```

Essentially, the `addTo*()` method takes care of the join table.

## GSP

So that takes care of persistence. As for the GSP... well on StackOverflow asking multiple questions at once is frowned upon. But here's the general idea with very minimal HTML/GSP:

```
<g:each var="student" in="${students}">
  <g:each var="course" in="${student.courses}">
    <p>${student.id}  ${student.fullName}  ${course.id}  ${course.courseName}</p>
  </g:each>
</g:each>
```

For more on the GSP, please create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Your joinTable mapping needs correction. [`joinTable`](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/joinTable.html) either accepts a String or a Map with keys `name`, `key`, and `column`.

**Change**

```
courses joinTable: "STUDENT_COURSE", key: "COURSE_ID"
```

and

```
students joinTable: "STUDENT_COURSE", key: "STUDENT_ID"
```

**To**

```
courses joinTable: [name: "STUDENT_COURSE", key: "COURSE_ID"]
```

and

```
students joinTable: [name: "STUDENT_COURSE", key: "STUDENT_ID"]
```